# The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'executions', database 'SSISDB', schema 'internal'

Tags: sql-server, select, ssis, sql-server-2014, sql-agent-job

I'm using SQL Server 2014 SP2.  I have a SSIS Package that executes 100% interactively via Visual Studio.

When I deploy to the SSIS Catalog and schedule via a SQL Agent Job I receive the below message.

The SQL Agent Account is being executed via a Proxy Account which in turn is a Role Member of the SSIS_Admin Role.

```
The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'executions', database 'SSISDB', schema 'internal'
```

I'm assuming this is permissions? How do I resolve or where should I at least be looking?

Comment: Are running it on you local machine or on the network. If you are running it on local machine log in as administrator buy write clicking on the sql server and run as administer. if on network you need permission granting

Comment: Running as local administrator has nothing to do with this, @JonWay . Local or Network.

Comment: To answer, yes, it is on the network.  I think its actually permissions on the SSIS DB though

Comment: user account, which is begin used to run the SqlServer agents jobs, has to be given access on SSISDB database.

Comment: @AnkitTyagi The job is called via a proxy account and this a Role Member of the 'ssis-admin' role

Answer (score 1):

are you running the package with SQL Agent Service Account? If yes, service account should have permissions on SSISDB. you can check it here:

[image]

If you have created a proxy and run the package with it, that user in the proxy should have permissions in SSISDB. You can check if the proxy account exists here:

[image]

Comment: It is executing via a Proxy Account and I do see that Proxy Account under Proxies \ SSIS Package Execution.  If I go to the Proxy Account Properties 'SQL Integration Services Package' is ticked, but nothing else.

Comment: when you go to proxy account properties, there is a tab which is "Credential Name". note it and then go to Security - Credentials. there should be the credential. Proxy account is connected to it. can you check the account permissions which is defined in the credential?

Comment: There is no Credential Name tab - only General \ Principals \ References

Comment: sorry "tab" was wrong word. It is placed in General Tab, under Proxy Name, there is Credential Name

Comment: got it - when you say go back to Security - Credentials, do you mean SSISDB \ Security \ Users?

Comment: you can see here: https://bidunyasi.files.wordpress.com/2014/05/cred3.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208183/discussion-between-michael-and-mehmet).

Answer (score 0):

Set dbo as the owner of internal schema. This fixed the issue for me.